# Strip out sensitive information from BIOS dump

Tags: reverse-engineering, bios

While debugging or reverse engineering a BIOS, what should be removed before sending a dump to someone else?

- Obviously, the serial number can easily be changed using a hex editor
  and searching for it in ascii (or unicode) string.
- The BIOS password, if set, is probably in plain text too.

What else would be important to remove? What else in a BIOS could be useful to a 3rd party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the **serial number** and the **BIOS password**, if any, and you should be fine.

TPM keys and such are not stored in the BIOS (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to protect yourself *from*?  If you were, for example, doing a secure system, you just wouldn't send it -- who knows what might have been encoded covertly?

Comment: Simply trying to avoid sending too much info for no reasons. If someone send his dump on a forum containing the serial number I guess someone else could register the system with the manufacturer (provided with a little more social engineering - purchase date, etc).

Comment: Well, the key is to ask yourself how much you want to protect it.  If you're really paranoid, you'd need to think about what could be steganographically hidden in the BIOS.